# How do I wrap Hinging with a HingeProcess?

Tags: prism, ioc-container

I'm missing something. I seem to be registering ok, but my resolve blows up with the following exception.

{"The type Test.Interfaces.IProcess`1 is an open generic type. An open generic type cannot be resolved.\r\nParameter name: t"}

How do I wrap Hinging with a HingeProcess, I thought registerInstance took care of this?

```
public interface IProcess<T> where T : class
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; set; }
    T Entity { get; set; }
}

public class HingingProcess<T> : IProcess<T> where T : class
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Expression { get; set; }
    public T Entity { get; set; }

    public HingingProcess(T entity)
    {
        Entity = entity;
    }
}

container.RegisterType(typeof(IProcess<>), typeof(HingingProcess<>), "HingeProcess",
                   new InjectionConstructor(new GenericParameter("T", "entity")));
        Hinging a = new Hinging();
        container.RegisterInstance<Hinging>("entity", a);

var pp = container.Resolve(typeof(IProcess<>), "HingeProcess", new ParameterOverrides[] { });
```

Thought maybe this would work, but fails to register.

```
            container.RegisterType<object, Hinging>("hinge");

        container.RegisterType(typeof(IProcess<>), typeof(HingingProcess<>), "HingeProcess",
       new InjectionConstructor(new GenericParameter("entity", "hinge")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type of the IProcess while resolving

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType(typeof(IProcess<>), typeof(HingingProcess<>), "HingeProcess",new InjectionConstructor(new GenericParameter("T", "entity")));
Hinging a = new Hinging();         
var pp = container.Resolve(typeof(IProcess<Hinging>), "HingeProcess", new ParameterOverride("entity", a));
```